# Hoare triple with unknown variable in postcondition

Tags: correctness, hoare-logic

I am reasoning about an Hoare Logic's exercise.

I should find all the boolean expressions `B` and all the programs `S` and `P` which satisfy the triple `{true} if B then S; if B then P; {a >= 0}`, assuming that the evaluation of `B` cannot modify the store, but the execution of `S` may modify it and change the value of `B`.

In particular, I don't know what I can say about `a`, because it is present just in the postcondition and I have never found an example like this.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: You could just use `a` in `S` and/or `P`. If `B` is false then neither `S` nor `P` are executed and thus the only way for `a` to be greater equal `0` would be some kind of default initialization. Do you have such a thing? If `B` is true then the postcondition holds for either `{B}S{a >= 0, ~B}` and any `P` (since then `P` is not executed) or `{B}S{B}` and `{B}P{a >= 0}`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(My previous answer was wrong.)

The question is kind of open-ended since there are an infinite number of expressions (`B`) and programs (`S` and `P`) satisfying the triple. Also, the triple is complex enough to prevent reducing the task to a simple general answer.

Basically you could break it down as follows:

- For all states in which `B` is false, `a >= 0` must hold (otherwise the triple as a whole could not hold)
- For the states in which `B` is `true`, the program `S; if B then P` must ensure that `a >= 0`
- This holds for all `S`, `B` and `P` such that...

  - either `S` makes `B` false and `a >= 0`
  - or, `S` makes `B` true, and ...,

etc.